# Achieving high concurrency in app that performs reading/writing to database?

Tags: concurrency, architecture, software-design

I'm working to design a middle layer for an application that will receive up to ~5000 requests every few seconds and need to retrieve information from a database. I've been looking at use the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools) (I use scala for my REST api design) as they say its fully async and built on Akka. However, the main bottleneck of any solution seems to happen during read/writes to the database. Many Database cannot support simultaneous read/writes from a database of such a scale. How is such high concurrency achieved then for an app like this? I would guess Facebook/Twitter/ (name other big company) may have achieved this for their Applications as millions of people may be using them concurrently.

Comment: Well you can look into using some sort of cache on top of your database, which might help the reads and/or writes.  Speaking of which, what is your intended database?

Comment: Something like MySQL or AWS Aurora.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim's comment was saying caching may or may not be able to help in your case. If not I would also recommend looking into horizontally scalable databases, for example [cockroachdb](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/) if you want a transactional SQL db. Otherwise there are many no-sql choices a la [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-scale) etc. And if you really want to stick to traditional SQL systems you'll have to vertically scale your servers (buy the most expensive hardware) and work with [read-replicas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html).

Answer (score 0):

A huge component is your data model and query access pattern.  If each query is incrementing a shared counter that has to be synchronized there will be a ton of contention, but if each query is touch completely separate data on the other end the spectrum than there will be a lot less contention.

I think there are a couple of dimensions I would consider:

**Data Schema and Access Patterns** (discussed above)

**Language Choice** 
This is important becaues if you were in a web server context and were using prefork by default each process may have its own connection to the database.  In an environment like python or ruby you may need hundreds of processes to handle your load.  Contrast this with akka or another async networking based runtime (node, python gevent/asyncio, go, etc) where a single instance with a small thread pool can handle a large number of requests. Each have their tradeoffs.

**Distributed Systems**

Depending on your data schema and access patterns 5000 requests per second to a RDBMS is completely achievable.  It would probably require relatively beefy hardware but but I'v personally done it a number of times.  Getting to larger scales requires more computers in order to distribute the work/load.  If your workload is right heavy and you can support potentially stale reads, a [read replica](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) is one option.  With another machine in the mix reads are distributed over 2 machines but writes are still directed at a single machine (leader).  Caching is another option.

At much higher workloads some sort of partitioning needs to occur in order to overcome the constraints of a single machine.  https://github.com/vitessio/vitess

Many of the big contenders have solutions to horizontally scaling their databases.  This has many drawbacks as well and will require careful planning.

---

The one thing I'd recommend is that if 5000 requests per second is projected for the near future, start with the minimal amount of hardware necessary (single instance) query patterns and operation get exponentially more complicated with a distributed database.